# How do I designate a startup project in VS Code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

How do I designate a startup project in VS Code?

**Context:**

In Visual Studio, I right click a project within solution explorer and set it as startup.

However, I am not clear on how to accomplish this in VS Code.

**Note:**

I recently added a WebAPI project to my directory in VS Code.

Answer (score 22):

This maybe deserves a better answer. So let me explain. In Visual Studio Code you have to set up your startup projects all in the **launch.json** and the **tasks.json** files.

Here is a small detailed **introduction**:

1. Choose a root project folder (i.e.: D:/anyfolder/myrootfolder)
2. Create two folders for two projects in the root folder
   2.1 **D:/anyfolder/myrootfolder/project1** 
   2.2 **D:/anyfolder/myrootfolder/project2**
3. Open cmd and create two Console-Applications (I use .netcore 2.0) 
   3.1 go to folders **project1** and **project2** using cmd (Command: cd -foldername-) 
   3.2 for each of that folders execute the command: **dotnet new console**
4. Open the root project folder with Visual Studio Code
5. Add the following **launch.json** and **tasks.json** to the .vscode folder (usually the .vscode folder is generated after clicked the debug-button in VS Code) 
   For More information visit:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Sample **launch.json** file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch Project1",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/project1/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/project1.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/project1",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch Project2",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/project2/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/project2.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/project2",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sample **tasks.json** file:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/project1/project1.csproj"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/project2/project2.csproj"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Don't forget that I used **.netcore 2.0**. If you use another Target Framework you have to customize the upper sample files of course.

After all you should now see two items in right of the Play(Debug-)button: 
**.NET Core Launch Project1** and 
**.NET Core Launch Project2**

This worked for me and my purposes...

Comment: I have a project that created and built in visual studio environment. This answer is useful to migrate project to vs code environment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are two tasks named "build." How does the selected project know which to use?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the SDK https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/sdk-for-vs-code
2. Restart your `Visual Studio Code`
3. Run `dotnet run` in the terminal of the root of your project, assuming the project has the correct setup it'll build and run your `.NET/C#` project, which I guess is the question about