# How to set a .NET project as StartUp in VS Code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with the [vscode-solution-explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer) to develop a .NET solution.

For debugging, I've configured my `.vscode/launch.json` file to run a build solution task and to execute a specific C# project (.csproj file).

My problem is: this .NET solution uses the Microservices approach, so I have ~50 Web API projects and each time I need to debug a specific API, I need to open the `.vscode/launch.json` file and replace the project name in 4 different places.

What I would like to do is the same that I do in Visual Studio: I right-click in the project and select "Set as StartUp project", so every time I press F5 it will run this selected project.

My `launch.json` looks likes this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MyProject",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/MyProject/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/MyProject.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/MyProject.csproj",                
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not using Visual Studio (community/pro/enterprise) ?

Comment: i think this can't be done from visual studio code.

Comment: @Cid My team is trying to switch to VS Code for many reasons (costs, features, lightweight, etc.)

Comment: @cash VS community is free

Comment: Well the difference between Code and VS is when you set a project as a startup project, VS doing the config modification task for you. So maybe there might be an extension to do it on Code.

Comment: @Cid Visual Studio Community is not free for big companies, only for individuals, colleges, open source companies, etc.

Comment: @ycansener If I could change the project to run in just one place, it would be better than the current approach where I need to replace in for different places in the launch.json file. I tried using an environment variable in launch.json, but [it didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363911/how-to-create-user-defined-variables-in-vs-code-launch-json).

Comment: **See Also**: [How do I designate a startup project in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46705521/1366033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple configurations in launch.json file.
Check this post: [How do I designate a startup project in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705521/how-do-i-designate-a-startup-project-in-vs-code)

Hope this helps.