# Visual Code still runs old project and doesn't run a new one

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

So I have a massive problem.
I have currently decided to learn C# and I am using Visual Code for this.

As you can see my structure is like so

[image: Image of file structure]

So here is my problem:

I create new folder called Project1.I Create new .NET console using the dotnet new console command and use run the file.Visual Code will create a new .vscode folder with launch.json and task.json (I don't know why and what that is)
Now when I add some code to Project1 I can run it perfectly, but the problem comes when I create a second project (Project2).
Again I create new folder and use dotnet new console command to create new .NET console, I add some code to the Project2 and run it but Visual Code will still run the Project1.

Is there a way how to stop this ? I can't figure out how, I also have Visual Studio installed but I don't want to use it, as it takes very long to load on my potato PC and Visual Studio has lots of extensions that help me alot.

I have the C# extensions installed, .NET CORE installed and the normal .NET installed

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705521/how-do-i-designate-a-startup-project-in-vs-code

Comment: Thank you, I tried looking at that but sadly it still doesn't work, Visual Code still runs the first project even after rebuilding the projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I had to reinstall Visual Code as Visual Studio was blocking access to compiler